# Show where you were referenced in the page title

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

In chat, as well as showing the unread count in the page (i.e. browser tab) title, also show an indication that you were refereed to (`@name`) in one of those unread messages.

```
(5) Chat Feedback
```

could become

```
(5#) Chat Feedback
```

Updated: as Marc noted, 5+ is likely to be interpreted as >5.

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of an asterisk or an exclamation mark instead of a plus sign. Great idea.

Answer (score 1):

I like that. I suspect "5+" is a bit misleading, perhaps (I imagine lots of queries: does that mean "more than 5?") - but interesting idea.

Comment: You could use an asterisk, octothorpe, or caret instead of the plus sign.

Comment: Good point, `#` would be better.

Comment: How about @, wouldn't that be more understandable?